# How to create a dynamic Model with Eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am refactoring an old database and I would like to quickly query/modify a table in different databases.

For instance I have 20 different databases named with company department numbers:

```
DbNameWeird-100
DbNameWeird-125
DbNameWeird-245
DbNameWeird-336
...
```

Each database have the same structure. What I would like to do is a full refactoring where instead of having 20 different connections I could do:

```
Foo::where('department', 125)->all();
```

To goal in mid-term is to merge these databases together by adding a new primary key column named `department` on each table. But currently I would simply do:

```
$foo = Foo($department);
$foo->all();
```

To go in this direction I need to get my connections:

```
foreach($departments as $dep) {
    DB::addConnection(dbConnection("DbNameWeird-{$dep}"), "db-{$dep}");
}
```

Then I need to dynamically update the `protected $connection` of my `Foo` model.

To kill two birds with one stone I wrote this:

```
class Foo extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'foo';
    protected $connection;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function __construct($department) {
        DB::addConnection(dbConnection("DbNameWeird-{$department}"), "db-{$department}");

        $this->connection = "db-{$department}";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

dd((new Foo(42))->all());
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I get this error:

```
Too few arguments to function Foo::__construct(), 0 passed in
project/portal/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php
on line 460 and exactly 1 expected
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough in Eloquent models, but shouldn't you pass an argument to parent::__construct(); ?

Comment: You will need to extend every method of the base eloquent Model that instantiate a new model object to pass that argument you want.

Comment: Well, unfortunately not :( it seems the `->all()` recall the constructor back without argument

Comment: @EliasSoares damned :( It is not a good news. Is there an alternative way to alter the protected property `connection`?

Comment: You can make it a static, and create a static method to change it value. But keep in mind that it will be valid for all instances, so you will always need to set it.

Comment: Try this: make your parameter optional (defining a defaut value). Create a static property to store the departament. If the departament parameter is present on constructor, you change the value of the static property. After it, use the static value to set the connection name. You will always need to start your eloquent calls using a constructor, but it should work.

Comment: Also, I didn't realized why you need this, might me you can solve in another way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272826/is-there-another-way-to-setconnection-on-an-eloquent-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [recommended solution](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections):

> **[Using Multiple Database Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections)**
>
> When using multiple `connections`, you may access each connection via the connection method on the `DB` facade. The `name` passed to the `connection` method should correspond to one of the connections listed in your `config/database.php` configuration file:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
> ```
>
> You may also access the raw, underlying PDO instance using the getPdo method on a connection instance:
>
> ```
> $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
> ```

---

If you need to change connections on `Eloquent models` and **`DB` is not enough**:

You can also define the connection at runtime via the [setConnection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1237) method

```
$foo = (new Foo)->setConnection('DbNameWeird-100');
$foo->first(); // or $foo->all();
```

---

Or you can use the [on method](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_on) like this:

```
Foo::on('DbNameWeird-100')->first();
Foo::on('DbNameWeird-125')->first();
```

Comment: Unfortunately with the `DB::connection()->all()->first()` the `->update()` method is not available. So I wrote a model, perhaps I don't need this

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer to fix your needs, but before that let me ask why don't you write two different `Model` with two different `connection` (which is a better practice, though)?

Comment: I have modified my question to be more specific and avoid to fall into a X-Y problem

Comment: I guess you are just looking for the `setConnection` method. You do not have to modify your model's constructor.